# Create Custom page with custom domain

Tags: custom-post-types, pages

I'm new to WordPress and I've tried to Search for my problem but I don't know what should I search for!

I have 5 pages called portfolio (multiple kinds of portfolio), all of them have the same structure, but the data are not the same of course.

I need to create a new page type and make their permalink be something like this:

/portfolio/company1

/portfolio/company2

How Can I achieve something like this?

Note, I've already tried Custom Post type plugin but I don't know Where to start from??

Comment: What is it that you're wanting to accomplish with creating separate post types? Since the structure is the same, you might be better just using Pages and you can then create Page Templates in your theme if you need to vary the visual display. Custom post types separate the content which can be useful if, say, you want to give certain editors access to edit some of the content but not all; and can also be useful if you have a reason to separate the structure; but if you don't have a specific reason to separate them there may be better approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the way WordPress uses permalinks is quite a simple process. You won’t need to install any plugins to do this. To access the settings for permalinks:

Go to the “Settings” section of your WordPress dashboard

One the left side of the dashboard under the “Settings” control, you should see one for “Permalinks.” This is what you should click.

Select the method you want to use and click the “Save Changes” button.

WordPress will automatically make the adjustments to your pages and post. This means you will not have to do anything more if you want the content to be saved a certain way.